# javascript effect for input form with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to replicate an effect I've seen on a form web page.

When the user clicks on an input field to insert a text

1. the placeholder label is moved on top
2. the bottom line border is highlighted with an animation

like the one you see here, but made with angular: http://md-pro-angular.creative-tim.com/forms/wizard

I think that gives a very clear and effective user experience, especially on long forms

Do you know if there is a plugin for jquery to create an effect like this?

Comment: Check my answer, i made it to start from the center ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a similar solution using only `css`, hope it helps.

```css
input:focus~label,
input:valid~label
{
  font-size: 0.75em;
  color: #999;
  top: -2.25rem;
  transition: all 0.625s cubic-bezier(0.2, 0, 0.03, 1);
}

.styled-input {
  float: left;
  width: 33.3333%;
  margin: 2rem 0 1rem;
  position: relative;
}

.styled-input label {
  color: #999;
  padding: 1rem;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  transition: all 0.25s cubic-bezier(0.2, 0, 0.03, 1);
  pointer-events: none;
}

input {
  padding: 1rem 1rem;
  border: 0;
  border-bottom:1px solid #999;
  width: 84%;
  font-size: 1rem;
}

input~span {
  display: block;
  width: 0;
  height: 3px;
  background: #e91e63;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  transition: all 0.625s cubic-bezier(0.2, 0, 0.03, 1);
}

input:focus {
  outline: 0;
}

input:focus~span {
  width: 100%;
  transition: all 0.625s cubic-bezier(0.2, 0, 0.03, 1);
}
```

```html
<div class="styled-input">
  <input type="text" required />
  <label>Name</label>
  <span></span>
</div>
```

Comment: many thanks!! it's perfect. I'll check how to have the highlight start from the center expanding on left and right.

Comment: @Giox You're welcome, is what is missing to be the same as the example of the question, =)

Comment: @Giox you may also have a look to my answer :)

Comment: @Giox, please look my answer, it is according to web standards using classie.js

Answer (score 1):

Here is a pure CSS solution for this :

```css
.input-container {
  max-width: 200px;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.input-container span {
  position: absolute;
  right: 50%;
  left:50%;
  height: 2px;
  bottom: 0;
  background: red;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

label {
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #a5a5a5;
  top: 20px;
  left: 10px;
  transition: 0.5s;
  cursor:initial;
}

input {
  padding: 20px 10px 10px;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #ccc;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

input:focus {
  outline: none;
}

input:focus+label {
  font-size: 12px;
  top: 5px;
}

input:focus~span {
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="input-container">
  <input id="in_1" type="text" />
  <label for="in_1">Label text</label>
  <span></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Of course, a solution with greater compatibility ;)

Answer (score -1):

Input must be look like **website** text field, not **mobile app** edit text field. See my solution according to **website standards** with classie.js, I have used classie.js inside script, you can include as separate file as resource inside head tag. Read more about classie.js, please visit https://github.com/desandro/classie

```js
/*classie.js  Strat*/ 

/*!
 * classie - class helper functions
 * from bonzo https://github.com/ded/bonzo
 * 
 * classie.has( elem, 'my-class' ) -> true/false
 * classie.add( elem, 'my-new-class' )
 * classie.remove( elem, 'my-unwanted-class' )
 * classie.toggle( elem, 'my-class' )
 */

/*jshint browser: true, strict: true, undef: true */
/*global define: false */

( function( window ) {

'use strict';

// class helper functions from bonzo https://github.com/ded/bonzo

function classReg( className ) {
  return new RegExp("(^|\\s+)" + className + "(\\s+|$)");
}

// classList support for class management
// altho to be fair, the api sucks because it won't accept multiple classes at once
var hasClass, addClass, removeClass;

if ( 'classList' in document.documentElement ) {
  hasClass = function( elem, c ) {
    return elem.classList.contains( c );
  };
  addClass = function( elem, c ) {
    elem.classList.add( c );
  };
  removeClass = function( elem, c ) {
    elem.classList.remove( c );
  };
}
else {
  hasClass = function( elem, c ) {
    return classReg( c ).test( elem.className );
  };
  addClass = function( elem, c ) {
    if ( !hasClass( elem, c ) ) {
      elem.className = elem.className + ' ' + c;
    }
  };
  removeClass = function( elem, c ) {
    elem.className = elem.className.replace( classReg( c ), ' ' );
  };
}

function toggleClass( elem, c ) {
  var fn = hasClass( elem, c ) ? removeClass : addClass;
  fn( elem, c );
}

var classie = {
  // full names
  hasClass: hasClass,
  addClass: addClass,
  removeClass: removeClass,
  toggleClass: toggleClass,
  // short names
  has: hasClass,
  add: addClass,
  remove: removeClass,
  toggle: toggleClass
};

// transport
if ( typeof define === 'function' && define.amd ) {
  // AMD
  define( classie );
} else {
  // browser global
  window.classie = classie;
}

})( window );

/*classie.js  Ended*/





(function() {
    // trim polyfill : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim
    if (!String.prototype.trim) {
     (function() {
      // Make sure we trim BOM and NBSP
      var rtrim = /^[\s\uFEFF\xA0]+|[\s\uFEFF\xA0]+$/g;
      String.prototype.trim = function() {
       return this.replace(rtrim, '');
      };
     })();
    }

    [].slice.call( document.querySelectorAll( 'input.input-field' ) ).forEach( function( inputEl ) {
     // in case the input is already filled..
     if( inputEl.value.trim() !== '' ) {
      classie.add( inputEl.parentNode, 'input-filled' );
     }

     // events:
     inputEl.addEventListener( 'focus', onInputFocus );
     inputEl.addEventListener( 'blur', onInputBlur );
    } );

    function onInputFocus( ev ) {
     classie.add( ev.target.parentNode, 'input-filled' );
    }

    function onInputBlur( ev ) {
     if( ev.target.value.trim() === '' ) {
      classie.remove( ev.target.parentNode, 'input-filled' );
     }
    }
   })();
```

```css
.input {
position: relative;
z-index: 1;
display: inline-block;
margin: 1em;
max-width: 350px;
width: calc(100% - 2em);
vertical-align: top;
}

.input-field {
position: relative;
display: block;
padding: 16px;
width: 60%;
border: none;
border-radius: 0;
background: #f0f0f0;
color: #aaa;
font-weight: 400;
font-size: 16px;
-webkit-appearance: none;
}

.input-field:focus {
outline: none;
}

.input-label {
display: inline-block;
float: right;
padding: 0 1em;
width: 40%;
color: #696969;
font-weight: bold;
font-size: 70.25%;
-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
-moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
-webkit-touch-callout: none;
-webkit-user-select: none;
-khtml-user-select: none;
-moz-user-select: none;
-ms-user-select: none;
user-select: none;
}

.input-label-content {
position: relative;
display: block;
padding: 1.6em 0;
width: 100%;
}



/* Yoshiko */
.input-field-animate {
width: 100%;
background-color: #d0d1d0;
border: 2px solid transparent;
-webkit-transition: background-color 0.25s, border-color 0.25s;
transition: background-color 0.25s, border-color 0.25s;
}

.input-label-animate {
width: 100%;
text-align: left;
position: absolute;
bottom: 100%;
pointer-events: none;
overflow: hidden;
padding: 0 1.25em;
-webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 3em, 0);
transform: translate3d(0, 3em, 0);
-webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.25s;
transition: transform 0.25s ;
-webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
}

.input-label-content-animate {
color: #8B8C8B;
padding: 0.25em 0;
-webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.25s;
transition: transform 0.25s;
-webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
}

.input-label-content-animate::after {
content: attr(data-content);
position: absolute;
font-weight: 800;
bottom: 100%;
left: 0;
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
color: #a3d39c;
padding: 0.25em 0;
text-transform: uppercase;
letter-spacing: 1px;
font-size: 0.85em;
}

.input-field-animate:focus + .input-label-animate,
.input-filled .input-label-animate {
-webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}

.input-field-animate:focus + .input-label-animate .input-label-content-animate,
.input-filled .input-label-content-animate {
-webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 100%, 0);
transform: translate3d(0, 100%, 0);
}

.input-field-animate:focus + .input-field-animate,
.input-filled .input-field-animate {
background-color: transparent;
border-color: #a3d39c;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" class="no-js">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>Animate Input</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <span class="input input-animate">
            <input class="input-field input-field-animate" type="text" id="input-10" />
            <label class="input-label input-label-animate" for="input-10">
                <span class="input-label-content input-label-content-animate" data-content="First Name">First Name</span>
            </label>
        </span>
    </body>
</html>
```